# SQL query from complete last week

Tags: sql, date

I'm busy making some SQL query easier to use. So we got one we run every week to calculate returns of bakers' wares. Therefore we edit 3 different SQL queries every week.

We change the dates, looks like this (`dep_eap.ADate Between '20140825' And '20140831'`)

The query is mostly run on Wednesdays but could also be Thursdays, so we can't make it by  counting the days. The week is from Monday to Sunday. Is there possibility to  make this in SQL?

Comment: mind posting your 3 queries?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: If you are on SQL server you can schedule a job to run at a spcific time & day. http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-to-schedule-sql-query-to-run-in-microsoft-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do

```
select * from your_table
where yearweek(date_column) = yearweek(curdate()) - 1
```